# convert python list to java array using py4j

Tags: java, python, variadic-functions, py4j

as the title say, I want to convert a list of string in python into a java array. After that, I will pass the java array  to a java method taking varargs arguments. And I use py4j.
In java, I have this method:

```
public static void MyJavaMethod(String ...myStrings){
//my method instructions
}
```

And in python, the only thing I could do is to convert my python list to JavaList but the trouble is that we can't pass Javalist to a method taking varargs arguments(only array):

```
from py4j.java_collections import SetConverter, MapConverter, ListConverter
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
mypythonlist=['string1', 'string2']
gateway = JavaGateway()
java_list = ListConverter().convert(mypythonlist, gateway._gateway_client)
# MyJavaArray=???
gateway.entry_point.MyJavaMethod(MyJavaArray)
```

So, I need to know how to convert python list to a java array using py4j. In java, we can perform it using `.toArray()` but I don't know how to do it from python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a methode from github that solve my problem:

```
from py4j.java_collections import SetConverter, MapConverter, ListConverter
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()
mypythonlist=['string1', 'string2']
object_class = gateway.jvm.java.lang.String
MyJavaArray = gateway.new_array(object_class, len(mypythonlist))
for i in range(len(mypythonlist)):
    my_array[i]=mypythonlist[i]
gateway.entry_point.MyJavaMethod(MyJavaArray)
```